# How to calculate average payoff with infinite/finite sums

Tags: calculus, geometric-series

This question relates to my study in microeconomics, where I sometimes have to calculate the average payoff. From my book, this is defined as:

$$(1-x) \sum_{i=1}^\infty v x^{i-1}$$

where $x$ is some discount factor $0 < x < 1$.

For example, if I want to calculate some expected payoff for an outcome $(5,0)$. Then if they play this strategy where they in the first period will receive $5$ and in the next will receive $0$, then I can show that this gets an average payoff by the above formula:

$$(1-x) \sum_{i=1}^n v x^{i-1} = (1-x)(5 \cdot \frac{1}{1-x^2} + 0 \cdot \frac{1}{1-x^2})$$

but if I instead had a finite sequence of payoffs, how would I derive an expression for the above? I know that this is simply a geometric sum, but I find it difficult to manipulate. And just to be sure, the reason that we get $1/(1-x^2)$ times either $5$ or $0$ is this because we only get either $5$ or $0$ every second time? If we would have just gotten $5$ every time I would assume we instead had $5 \cdot 1/(1-x)$. Is this correct? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Should it  be $x^{i-1}$ instead of $x^{n-1}$ in the sum? Otherwise you'd simply have $(1-x)\sum_{i=1}^nv_ix^{n-1} = (1-x)x^{n-1} \sum_{i=1}^n v_i$.

Comment: Yes, I changed it to $n=1$. It was a typo. It should be intrepted as we get $5 + 0 \cdot x + 5 \cdot x^2 + 0 \cdot x^3 \dots $

Comment: Okay but now the $v_i$ are independent of the index $n$? Also, writing $\sum_{n=1}^n$ can be very confusing.

Comment: Ye, ok, I see. I will change it accordingly. $v_i$ should be intrepted for $i = 1,2$ such that it changes like the above. Maybe the notation is a little bit weird, but I hope you understand what I am trying to do.

Comment: @Mathias What is $v_i$? Please include it in the question and please define it.

Comment: $v$ is a vector of payoff. In my example $v = (5,0)$ which means that first they get $5$, then $0$, then $5$ and so on so we get the infinite series $5 + 0 \cdot x + 5 \cdot x^2 + 0 \cdot x^3 \dots$. My question was what is the closed form of a series like this? For example how large would $n$ have to be to get some certain expected outcome? If we sum up to infinity we see that the average payoff when $x = 1$ is simply $2.5$, but what if I wanted to solve for $n$ which gives a lower/higher outcome?